# ¿Hay manera de tener todos los scripts que uno importa en un solo archivo JS?

Tags: javascript, html

Trabajo con HTML y siempre me he preguntado si hay manera de tener todos los scripts que uno importa (de Google o otras fuentes) en un archivo aparte.

Recuerdo que en Laravel podía tener todo en uno solo, pero acá siempre tengo que hacer los llamados.

¿Hay una manera de hacer todo esto sin ponerlos en cada página? ¿Alguna función de JS vainilla sin frameworks? ¿O debo usar uno como Vue JS?

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/plugins.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>


<script src="assets/js/1.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/2.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/3.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/4.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/5.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/6.js"></script>


<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXX-X"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X');
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Podrías usar un *bundler* para crear un script que contenga todos los demás. Algunos populares: *browserfy*, *parcel*, *esbuild*, *rollup*, *webpack*.